# iOS 7 Table View Landscape Cell Width

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've added a table view to a UI View Controller. When I rotate the phone into landscape mode the cell width isn't completely filling the view. See the below screenshot.

Cannot seem to find an elegant solution here.

[image]

EDIT: you can download my example of the landscape view not resizing here:

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/tableviewresize.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the UITableView using auto layout or with the appropriate autoresizing masks.

***PROGRAMATICALLY***

**Auto Layout:**

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tableview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"tableView" : tableView };

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|"
                                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView]|"
                                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDictionary]];
```

**Autoresizing Masks:**

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

***INTERFACE BUILDER / STORYBOARD***

**Auto Layout:**

Control drag from the table view to the superview and add these constraints:

[image: Layout Constraints]

**Autoresizing Masks (No Auto Layout):**

These should be the autosizing mask for the table view if you are using manual frame manipulation

[image: Autoresizing Masks]

***NOTE***

In all seriousness dude, I have given you as clear away as I can to size your view appropriately to make it flexible. If you struggle to understand this then I suggest you go back and look at a few tutorials for Beginning iOS Development. [RayWenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com) is an amazing resource for everything you can think of when starting iOS.

**UPDATE**

Your test project with the added constraints. It literally took me about 5 seconds to do it. Look at the iPhone storyboard.

http://speedy.sh/2jDwY/tableviewresize.zip

Comment: but i'm not programatically adding the table view to the view controller. i've dragged and dropped it to the view. i am never actually "newing" up the table view as you illustrate. would the same apply?

Comment: Infinity James sorry to leave this hanging - i'm going to try this out tonight and mark accepted if so :)

Comment: I'm still unsure how to get this to work. would you be able to provide a simple sample xcode project that shows a Table View living on a regular view that grows when in landscape mode? the funny thing is if i drop a navigation controller on there the table view it comes with does this out of the box but i can't replicate.

Comment: infity james: i've uploaded a dead simple example project above to illustrate my issue

Comment: No point in answering a question just in the hope to get points. I'm glad I could actually help you man, that's why I bothered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apple iOS 7 orientation resize table view has some issue.

Using following into right place can resolve problem.

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Along with this call, if need one may also have to change width as per new orientation size in `cellforRowIndexPath` data source.